# How to Open Facebook page links in website in the Facebook App

Tags: html, facebook, deep-linking, facebook-page

Good day

I having a simple wordpress site where I am linking to facebook pages

for example

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookIndia" target="_blank">Open my Page</a>`

This works works normally in desktop it open a new tab.

When I am in mobile it still opens the same way in browser but I need the links to open in facebook native app.

How do I handle it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to create a fallback link if the app is not installed.

reference link from google
[Google Deep Links with Intents](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/android/intents/)

Also here is my complete final version of code
[Gist of complete JS code to handle facebook links](https://gist.github.com/sudarshann/ab3fdb922d3d068cfda6fc466e22c647)

Comment: For me, this opens the FB app but does not take me to the page I want. It just opens the default home page of the FB app. Any ideas why this might be the case?

Comment: Got it. In your code, you put the page name as the name id. Instead, one needs to find the page id for his page. To find your Page ID:
(1) Log into Facebook, then click your profile photo in the top right.
Click See all Profiles, then select the Page you want to switch into.
(2) Click your Page's name in the left menu to go to it.
(3) Click the About tab below your Page's cover photo, then click Page transparency.
(4) Click See all, then click Go to Ad Library.
(5) Find view_all_page_id= in the address bar of your browser. Your Page ID is the number immediately following this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this link :

Android : fb://page/PAGEID

iOS : fb://profile/PAGEID

Retrieve PAGEID on https://www.facebook.com/help/1503421039731588

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. This does work for me. But I have another follow up question. Say if I dont have facebook app installed it doesnt open anything for me. But I have another device where I have the app installed it does open. Any suggestion on how to handle this situvation. 
Thanks

Comment: Although the complete fix is here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68492022/1560096