# How to open links in Facebook app on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, url

I have a simple static website where I have a link to my Facebook page. When clicked from mobile browsers, it opens in the browser. But I want it to open in the Facebook app installed on the user's iPhone.
I tried these URL Schemes `<a href="fb://page/10101225458">Facebook App iPhone</a>` and `<a href="fb://profile/10101225458">Facebook App iPhone</a>` and None worked on iPhone. However it works nicely on Android. How to make it work on iPhone/iOS? Thanks.

I tried this link [How to Open Facebook page links in website in the Facebook App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68491231/how-to-open-facebook-page-links-in-website-in-the-facebook-app) and none of the suggestions on that thread worked.
P.S. I tested it online on testingbot